# Find the missing number :

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, logic-grid

Find the missing number in the following table.

[image]

Answer Options are:

- 25
- 27
- 32
- 30

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: One of the old question papers of competitive examination I am preparing for. @BeastlyGerbil However, I don't understand the reason for down votes.

Comment: @MansiManhas It's most likely because people think you should be posting at math.stackexcahnge; math puzzles tend to be frowned on the puzzling stack over riddles, cryptography, etc. There is nothing wrong with the actual problem itself though.

Comment: @pie314271 Thanks for letting me know. I would take care of it in the future.

Comment: Downvotes are likely a combination of two things: 1, Puzzles that aren't yours should only be posted with proper attribution. This is important to fix, because we hold a very dim view of plagiarism and it can result in question deletion and sometimes bannings. 2, puzzles of this style, while on-topic, are sometimes downvoted as not being particularly interesting, or due to only being soluble in multiple-choice format.

Comment: -1 for a diagram so poor, its characters are less legible than plain text.
But not -1 for posting a maths puzzle. Maths puzzles are on topic and are OK.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is from an exam that is not properly attributed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is equal to:

> 30

Reason:

> 2 + 1 = 3,
>  3 + 2 = 5,
>  5 + 3 = 8,
>  8 + 4 = 12,
>  12 + 5 = 17,
>  17 + 6 = 23,
>  23 + 7 = **30**,
>  30 + 8 = 38.
>  We're adding an incremented counter to the values and the path is left to right, down, right to left, down, left to right.

Answer (score -1):

ANSWER IS

> 30
> first series 2+1 = 3, 3+2 = 5   increasing
> second series 17-5 = 12, 12-4 = 8  decreasing
> third series 23+7 = 30, 30+8 = 38 increasing

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**)  We generally put Spoiler tags around answers to avoid revealing the answers to someone who wants to try to solve the puzzle on their own.